# Is it possible to efficiently check whether STL std::deque erase succeded?

Tags: c++

We are trying to use the std::deque erase member function. The return value of the std::deque erase(iterator) member function is a A random access iterator pointing to the new location of the element that followed the last element erased by the function call, which is the container end if the operation erased the last element in the sequence.

We were wondering whether it is possible to efficiently check whether STL std::deque erase succeded. Thank you. An excerpt of our code is shown below:

```
typedef std::multimap<char *,Range>::const_iterator I;
std::pair<I,I> b = mmultimap.equal_range(TmpPrevMapPtr);

for (I i=b.first; i != b.second; ++i){ 
   std::deque<Range>::iterator iter;
   std::deque<Range>::iterator it;
   iter = std::lower_bound(ranges_type.begin(),ranges_type.end(),i->second);
   if (iter != ranges_type.end() && !(i->second < *iter)){
       it = ranges_type.erase(iter);
   }
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged both `linux` and `visual-c++`? That seems like a strange combination. Also, you might want to fix your code block.

Comment: Sven , The code we are trying for our prototype deduper must work on Linux and Windows Visual C++. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the size of dequeue decreases by the number of elements you erased.
With regards to the concern about performance, Time Complexity for `dequeue::size` is `O(1)`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  unsigned int i;
  deque<unsigned int> mydeque;

  // set some values (from 1 to 10)
  for (i=1; i<=10; i++) mydeque.push_back(i);

  cout << "\nmydeque contains:"<<mydeque.size();

  // erase the 6th element
  mydeque.erase (mydeque.begin()+5);

  // erase the first 3 elements:
  mydeque.erase (mydeque.begin(),mydeque.begin()+3);

  //Total Elements erased = 4

  cout << "\nNow mydeque contains:"<<mydeque.size();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How long does it take to find the size ofa deque 0(1) or 0(N)? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer with the code example and verifying that std::deque::size is a 0(1) operation. We will try your answer.Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`std::deque::erase` always succeeds (unless of course, it gets an invalid iterator, in which case the results are undefined).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We wondering if it is efficiently possible to determine whether an std::deque::erase gets an invalid iterator? Thank you.

Comment: No, just keep checking against `end()` and make sure you don't re-use iterators after operations that invalidate them. For `std::deque`, the rule is *If the erasing is performed on the beginning or the end of the sequence, only the iterators and references to the erased elements are invalidated. If the deletion happens in the middle of the deque, all iterators and references are invalidated.*

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Isn't it possible that stq::deque::erase(iterator) returns end() if we delete the last  element of the deque. If we check against end() , we may ignore the case where std::deque::erase erases the last element of the deque. Thank you.

Comment: @Frank, I think you can accept only one answer, but I don't mind if it isn't mine :-)

Answer (score 1):

If the erase succeeded the deque will be shorter than it was. Alternatively, wrap your code in a function (which you should be doing in any case) and have the function return whether or not an erase happened.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth, Thank you for your answer. Do you know whether std::deque::size is an BIG-O(1) or BIG-o(N) operation? Thank you.

Comment: @Frank I don't believe the standard specifies the required complexity for size() for a deque.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth. Thank you for reply. Should we look in Microsoft STL  and GNU STL implementation code to find out the time complexity for size() in deque. Alternatively, Is there another place where we find the time complexity of std::deque::size() in Microsoft STL or GNU LINUX STL? Thank you.

Comment: @Frank Use the source! For GCC, it seems to be O(1), but don't take my word for it.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth, Thank you for your reply. We will use the GCC source code and Microsoft STL code for std:::deque::size(). Thank you.